# How to upload file on SD card to Arduino webpage

Tags: arduino

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but I'm trying to upload Calendar.csv, a file on my SD card in the Arduino, to the webpage created by my Arduino. This would allow users to download Calendar.csv from my local website. Is this possible?

Oh, and the file changes with the user's settings, so it's not static.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but will need sketch improvment.